# How to retrieve a last row cell value

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

I want to retrieve the last row cell value

datagrid

```
01 Rajan
02 Vijayan
03 Suresh
```

Tried Code like this

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To datagrid1.RowCount - 1 
            textbox1.text = datagrid1.currentrow.Cells(0).Value 'current row
            textbox2.text = datagrid1.row(i).Cells(0).Value 'last row
 Next
```

Last row is showing null

Expected Output

```
textbox2.text = 03
```

What wrong in my code, need vb.net code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

.Rows is a collection, and also works like an array, and the index numeration of arrays goes from 0 to N-1

Comment: I tried with ur code, datagrid1.Rows(datagrid1.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value, it showing null, can u help me..

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use linq; `dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().LastOrDefault()` will give you the final row or null if no rows are present.

Comment: You would need `dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>.LastOrDefault()`

Comment: Good spot, edited :) I assume `.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()` would work and probably save on type-checking?